# SSH kex_exchange_identification returning HTTP response in banner line

Tags: windows, github, ssh, openssh

I'm not sure when this started happening, but I noticed it because it broke my ability to use Github.
I started encountering the error `key_exchange_identification: banner line too long` when trying to use any git commands that interact with the remote when the remote is Github (haven't tested with Enterprise GH or non-GH locations). Investigating further, I found that the underlying `ssh` commands were failing because the banner line contained an entire HTML document. `ssh -v -T git@ssh.github.com` output follows:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\lwrubles/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [192.30.255.123] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\lwrubles\\.ssh\\id_rsa_test type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\lwrubles\\.ssh\\id_rsa_test-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: HTTP/1.0 500 handshakefailed
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Content-Type: text/html
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: Cache-Control: no-cache
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: Content-Length: 17998
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: X-Frame-Options: deny
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5: Proxy-Connection: Close
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 6:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 7: <html><head>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 8:     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 9:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 10:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-300.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 11:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-300.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 12:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 13:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 14:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 15:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 16:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 17:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 18:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 19:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-600.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 20:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-600.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 21:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 22:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 23:     <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/font/Open_Sans/open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 24:     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/default/stylesheets/en.css">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 25:     <script src="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hm64ds/files/javascript/sw.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 26: </head>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 27:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 28: <body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 29:     <div class="container">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 30:         <div class="header">
```

I have tried:

- several different identity files, changed both in the config and on the command line;
- accessing `ssh.github.com` both directly (as above) and via a config file; and
- using a new blank config file.
  These all produced the same output.

I have also tried using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04, with its own identity and config files, and that worked perfectly fine, so I don't think it's a proxy or network issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [192.30.255.123] port 443.
```

According to this you're supposed to be connecting to port 443 on one of github's load balancers. When I connect to that address and port, I get an SSH server version string which is the expected result.

It seems likely that a firewall or similar network device, probably within your local network environment, is interfering with your connections to github. The "/mwg-internal" URL in the HTTP suggests that you're connecting to a  [McAfee Web Gateway](https://www.microsa.es/biblioteca/McAfee/web_gateway/mwg_product_7.3_PG-PRODUCT-0912-EN.pdf) instance.

You could try switching git to use HTTPS URLs for the repo that you're trying to access. If you need to connect through SSH, you should contact your local network administrators for help.